# How to create masonry layout using css only?

Tags: css, masonry

I want to create masonry layout using css only, i read all tutorial in internet, but they using column property to divide layout, the problem in here is the layout will be display like this (with 1,2,3...is a items).

```
1|3|5
2|4|6
```

I want my layout must be:

```
1|2|3
4|5|6
```

I want use css only.Please tell me if you have any solution or idea to resolve this problem.

Comment: Masonry is built on Javascript, as it detects positions and puts everything with position absolute. CSS can't detect positions, but you can use `@media queries` and `position:abolute`.

Comment: @DaanHeskes Using css is impossible, right?, So could you please give me some example ?

Comment: Definitely not Impossible, but not automatically aligning etc. That's what Javascript does. You can `position:absolute` everything and set the `top` and `left` offsets. Then change for smaller/bigger screens with CSS3 Media Queries.

Comment: Okey,thanks for help @DaanHeskes

Comment: haven't tried it but perhaps with flexbox, using flex-direction and flex-wrap. See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flexbox. See [codepen](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/eAqzk) for example, and [complete guide to flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to learn more.

In order to keep the layout horizontal, adjust the `flex-direction` to your liking.